# How do I executing some code in the objects class when I creating an object?

Tags: java, class, methods, random

I have a class named Tile and I execute "tile = new Tile()" which works fine and creates a tile in the window where I want it. But what if I want to randomize some of the initialized variables in the Tile class such as the initial x and y values? How would I do this? I tried creating a method that randomizes the variables but how would I get this code to execute when the tile is created?

Comment: call said method from the constructor? place the code to randomized the values in the constructor?

Comment: You want to know about _constructors_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a constructor to initialize values. A constructor is "a method" which will be called when you instantiate your object.

```
class Tile {

    private int someField;

    public Tile() {

        // do your stuff here
        this.someField = createRandomNumber();

        System.out.println(this.someField);
    }
}
```

Depending on your code, you could also initialize the value directly:

```
class Tile {

    private int someField = createRandomNumber();
}
```

But I would prefer the constructor, since it is somehow cleaner to initialize all stuff in one single place.

Comment: Thank you so much I had no idea I could do that.